# Detect if flask is being run via gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Is there a way I can check if my flask app is being run instide a gunicorn container? Currently I set an enviroment variable to tell my application this, but I'd prefer that it be automatic.  Additionally, is there someway I can check what worker class is being used?

---

I need to detect this for a few different reasons. Note that typically I use gunicorn, but during testing I won't sometimes.

1. Logging: I attach to a gunicorn info log when run in gunicorn, otherwise to a stdout log.
2. Eventlet/subprocess: Since I use subprocesses I need to ensure that the proper monkey_patch'ing is done when using eventlet, otherwise it doesn't behave correctly. (I call many subprocesses).

Comment: I am curious why do you want to detect this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, added some info to the question.

Answer (score 31):

Late to the party, but a very hacky solution that seems to work:

```
is_gunicorn = "gunicorn" in os.environ.get("SERVER_SOFTWARE", "")
```

Comment: This isn't "very hacky". It's a pretty standard way to pass data down the stream.

Comment: @TomaszZielinski The only reason I consider it hacky is that it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (AFAIK) and is therefore not guaranteed to be available or always in the same format. I would be more comfortable if gunicorn had a documented environment variable `IS_GUNICORN` that is defined when gunicorn imports my app.

Comment: I ended up adding an `IS_GUNICORN` environment variable to my startup scripts and use it.

Comment: For reference, you can see SERVER_SOFTWARE environment variable mentioned in the [0.11.2 / 2010-10-30](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/2010-news.html?highlight=SERVER_SOFTWARE#id2) Gunicorn changelog item and also in the [gunicorn/gunicorn/__init__.py](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/792edf6d9aabcbfb84e76be1d722ac49c32dc027/gunicorn/__init__.py#L9) Python code.

Comment: this worked :)  Thanks !  fyi, it's "documented" (kind of) at https://docs.gunicorn.org/_/downloads/en/20.1.0/pdf/